# Bias common source diode connected load

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, analog, circuit-analysis, nmos

To amplify small signal we need to bias M1 and M2 in saturation mode.
Obviously, M2 is always in saturation because Vgd = 0. 
However, how should I bias M1 in saturation?
[image]

Comment: Think about it for a minute, what needs to happen for M1 to be in saturation ? Or how would you force it into triode/linear mode ? What controls do you have ? Vin and Vdd. You're close because you already understand that M2 is always in saturation.

Comment: Hi, for M1 to be in saturation Vout > Vin  - Vth. I got stuck here because Vout and Vin are not fixed.

Comment: But for a given Vin, what could you do to make sure Vout is such that M1 is in saturation ? Note that we're talking DC biasing voltages here, we assume that the signal component on Vin is small. So in a way Vin and Vout are fixed, fixed at their DC biasing value. What would happen if you could change Vdd ?

Comment: Thank you. just for simplifying calculation, assuming that both transistor have the same W/L and threshold voltage Vth. So with the condition Id1 = Id2 we get Vout = Vdd - Vin. Now for M1 to be in saturation, Vout > Vin - Vth => Vdd - Vin > Vin - Vth or Vin < (vdd+Vth)/2. Does this mean that I need to apply a DC voltage less than (Vdd+Vth)/2 from gate to ground of M1? I think we need add another condition that Vin (DC bias voltage) > amplitude of small signal. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Just ignore the signal amplitude for the moment, it is easier to focus on one problem at a time :-) You're right, the Vgs of M1 must be kept below a certain value and /or you could increase Vdd. Both would make (the DC voltage at) Vout increase so that Vds of M1 would be large enough to make it operate in saturation. So: to keep M1 in saturation: Vgs must be small, Vds must be large.

Comment: The largest signal where M1 is still in saturation is where Vds = Vgs - Vt. This sets the max value of Vin. For smaller Vin M1 will still be in saturation. The smallest Vin is where Vgs becomes almost equal to Vt, there M1 starts to enter the weak inversion mode. Notice how by looking at the possible DC bias solutions I can find the (large signal) input voltage range ?

Comment: Hi, with smallest Vin = Vt then M1 is at the edge of weak inversion. However, when adding with small signal the total vin will be below Vt and M1 is in subthreshold region not saturation. So, should smallest Vin is Vt + amplitude of small signal?

Comment: Indeed you want to avoid the weak inversion / subtreshold region. But I was not suggesting to bias just above Vgs = Vt ! There would be no "room" for a signal anymore. The optimum biasing point would be somewhere between the highest Vin where M1 is still in saturation and Vin = Vt + 100 mV for example. So if Vin max would be 1 V, Vt = 0.6 V then a good choice for the biasing point would be Vin = 0.85 V, then a sinewave with an amplitude of 0.15V would be amplified with low distortion.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep M1 in saturation,

Vg - Vth = Vd for M1 to just be at the edge of saturation is the upper limit.

So,

The drain voltage needs to be equal to or higher value than gate voltage which brings us to :

Vg - Vth < Vdd -Vd

Thus,  Vg < (Vdd + Vth) / 2. (at the GATE node)

So, the gate node needs to biased satisfying  the above condition probably using a resistor divide bias.

The small signal voltage is then coupled at the input so that dc bias does not get affected.

The input gets amplified by a factor which is independent of the transconductance of the MOSFETs.

Gain = - sqrt((W1/L1) /(W2/L2) ). ( independent of gm is a good thing)

Replace the diode NMOS with a PMOS, you can get even higher gain because of the mobility factor in the expression.

**DEMERITS:**

However, the major problem with the above circuit is that the SWING is constrained by both the overdrive voltage and the threshold voltage because
if you replace W/L by the overdrive voltages in the expression.
Then,

GAIN = (|Vgs2 - Vth2|)/(Vgs1 -Vgs2).

So, if for transistor M1, say  overdrive =200mV then it would require 
|Vgs2| =2.7 Volts for a mere gain of 10 which clearly indicates the severe limitation on the output swing!

Comment: Thank you. You said "Vg = Vd for M1 to just be at the edge of saturation is the upper limit.". I am wondering why not Vg = Vd - Vt here?

Comment: To be precise,  Vg - Vd should be less than threshold voltage for the MOS to be in saturation region. If my answer has cleared your question, do mark it as completed, so that we can close this

Comment: @user3126592 If you think my answer is complete and was helpful to you. do click on the tick icon to close the question

Comment: Hi dexter, I already clicked before. However, my vote isn't accepted because I haven't earned 15 reputation yet. I appreciate your help.

Comment: yea alright, btw you can click on the TICK icon to mark the answer as appropriate one